# how to use offset,limit in PDO sql->prepare statement

Tags: sql, pdo, prepared-statement, limit, offset

I am doing sql prepare statement where I want to fetch data with limit and offest.
I dont know how to bindParam offset and limit.
Error I am facing:
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','6')' at line 1

here is my code,

```
$limit = 6;

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = 1;
}
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$sql4 = $con->prepare("select * from products order by id desc limit ?,?)");
$sql4->bindParam(1, $offset);
$sql4->bindParam(2, $limit);
$sql4->execute();
```

Comment: Isn't the `)` in `?,?)` the error?

Comment: still same error after removing braces

Comment: There's only one extraneous brace. Anyway, have a look here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit